# how do i export data as m3u8 file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to download and play m3u8 file which is on server machine. I am using following code to read and send m3u8 file to web server.
Browser is displaying contents of file instead of downloading it.
So please let me know that, how to download it.

```
if ((exportHandle = fopen(v3FileName, "a+")) != NULL) {
    long end = 0, start = 0, pos = 0;
    char* m3u8FileDataBuff = NULL;
    fseek(exportHandle, 0, SEEK_END);
    end = ftell(exportHandle);
    fseek(exportHandle, 0, SEEK_SET);
    start = ftell(exportHandle);
    pos = end - start;
    m3u8FileDataBuff = (char *) malloc(pos);
    end = 0;
    start = 0;
    fread(m3u8FileDataBuff, 1, pos, exportHandle);
    pClienCommunication->writeBuffer(m3u8FileDataBuff, pos);
    free(m3u8FileDataBuff);
    fclose(exportHandle);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client's web browser is displaying the content, because the MIME type of the response is either nil, or something like "text/plain". Set up the http response header properly to indicate mime type of m3u8 file (`application/x-mpegURL` or `vnd.apple.mpegURL`).

The piece of code you provided does not seem to set anything around response header, just content.

Check available API of `pClienCommunication->`, or place where that originates, what are your options to adjust response header.

Or maybe it's possible to work-around this also by some rule set up in the web server serving the response, to set the MIME type for certain URLs, or based on the response content (but applying such rules on web server level is usually more costly then adjusting the response while being created in the C++ part).

---

And why is this tagged C++, when the code itself is C-like with all the problems of it. In modern C++ you never do things like "fclose(..)", because that is done in the destructor of the file wrapper class, so you don't risk the fclose will be skipped in case of some exception raised in fread, etc.

So in modern C++ these things should look somewhat like this:

```
{
    SomeFileClass exportFile(v3FileName, "a+");
    if (exportFile.isOK()) {
        SomeFileContentBuffer data = exportFile.read();
        pClienCommunication->writeBuffer(data.asCharPtr(), data.size());
    }
}
```

So you can't forget to release any file handle, or buffer memory (as the destructors of particular helper classes will handle that).